# Limit of $n\cdot(1-\frac{1}{n})^{n\cdot \ln(n)}$ as $n \to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I am aware of the well-known limit that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = \frac{1}{e}$$

However, I am having trouble evaluating it within a more complex function that also depends on $n$. For example,

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}n\cdot\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n\cdot \ln(n)}$$

Can we nonetheless still evaluate the expression as

$$n\cdot \left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^{\ln(n)} = n \cdot n^{-1} = 1$$

Comment: Hint, if you're looking for a method that does work: $\tfrac1n+\ln(1-\tfrac1n)\sim-\tfrac{1}{2n^2}$.

Comment: The function gets simplified a lot once you take logs to get $\log n(1+n\log(1-1/n)) $.

Answer (score 4):

No, it doesn't work. However, the limit is indeed $1$. You have to use the fact that $$\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n\ln(n)}=e^{n\ln(n)\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)}.$$
Now, you have that $$\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)=-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2n^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right),$$
and thus $$n\ln(n)\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)=-\ln(n)+o\left(1\right).$$

Therefore $$n\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n\ln(n)}=e^{o(1)},$$
and thus the limit is indeed $1$.

---

**Edit**

The fact that $$\ln(1+x)=x+\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)$$ whenever $x\to 0$ is well known (see [Taylor Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series)). Moreover, notice that if $f(n)=o(g(n))$, then $f(n)=g(n)o(1)$.

So, we have that $$n\ln(n)\left(\frac{1}{2n^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)=\frac{\ln(n)}{2n}+\frac{\ln(n)}{n}o(1).$$
Since the RHS goes to $0$ whenever $n\to \infty $, it's a $o(1)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I know the little-o notation but am not super familiar with its arithmetic rules. May I ask how you get the second equation, and why $n \ln(n)o(1/n) = o(1)$?

Comment: @trembling_hands: I edited my answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to Surb's answer, your method won't work in general, as illustrated with this example:

$$
2 = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(2^{1 / n}\right)^n \neq \lim_{n\to\infty} 1^n = 1
$$